# Histogram bins size to equal 1 day - pyplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, statistics, histogram

I have this list of delivery times in days for cars that are 0 years old. The list contains nearly 20,000 delivery days with many days being repeated. My question is how do i get the histogram to show bin sizes as 1 day. I have set the bin size to the amount of unique delivery days there by:
 `len(set(list))`

but when i generate the histogram, the frequency of 0 delivery days is over 5000, however when i do `list.count(0)` it returns with 4500.

Comment: If you use `pyplot.hist`, the `bins` keyword can be passed an `array`-like, which denotes the bin edges. See the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, len(set(list)) is the number of unique values for the "delivery days" variable. This is not the same thing as the bin size; it's the number of distinct bins. I would use "bin size" to describe the number of items in one bin; "bin count" would be a better name for the number of bins.

If you want to generate a histogram, supposing the original list of days is called days_list, a quick high-level approach is:

1. Make a new set unique_days = set(days_list)
2. Iterate over each value day in unique_days
3. For the current day, set the height of the bar (or size of the bin) in the 
   histogram to be equal to days_list.count(day). This will tell you the number 
   of times the current "day" value for number of delivery days appeared in the 
   days_list list of delivery times.

Does this make sense?

If the problem is not that you're manually calculating the histogram wrong but that pyplot is doing something wrong, it would help if you included some code for how you are using pyplot.

Answer (score 0):

The number of bins would be determined by the number of days up to the maximum number of possible days.

Say `daylist` is the list you want to histogram (never call a list `list`, because that overwrites the python command with the same name), you would use the maximum of that list and create a range of bins like

```
maxi = max(daylist)
bins = range(0, maxi)
plt.hist(daylist, bins=bins)
```

or, if you want to use numpy,

```
bins = np.arange(0,np.max(daylist))
plt.hist(daylist, bins=bins)
```